# Joins not working in described condition

Tags: c#, sql, database, oledb

I have two tables.

Table1->Payment

```
AdmissionNum(PK)  |  StudName |   Fees |

       1               sagar      5000 
       2               nilesh     6000
       3               amar       4000
```

Table2-> paymentDetails

```
AdmissionNum(FK) | RemainingFees |   Date       |  Payment
        1             4000          1/1/2012          1000
        2             5000          2/5/2012          1000
        1             3500          2/10/2012         1500
        1             2500          2/15/2012         1000
        2             2500          2/20/2012         2500
        3             0             3/25/2012         4000
```

I have tried different queries but was not able to make joint between payment table and paymentDetails table.
I am making C# windows app. When particular student is paying fees his record is stored in paymentDetails table.
I want to extract only outstanding fees details i.e. student whose Remaining Fees is greater than 0 but the last details in the paymentDetais table i.e. .

My expected resut table is-

```
AdmissionNum  |  StudName |   Fees | RemainingFees

       1           sagar      5000    2500
       2           nilesh     6000    2500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
with cte as (select P.AdmissionNum , P.StudName,   P.Fees , D.RemainingFees,row_number() 
over ( partition by  P.AdmissionNum order by [DATE] desc) as rn
from Payment P
join PaymentDetails D
on P.AdmissionNum=D.AdmissionNum
where RemainingFees>0)
select AdmissionNum ,StudName,  Fees , RemainingFees
from cte
where rn=1
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f14fd/12)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows.

```
SELECT 
       P.AdmissionNum,
       P.StudName,
       P.Fees
       P.Fees - PD.Payment 'RemainingFees'
FROM
    Payment P
    JOIN (SELECT 
                AdmissionNum, 
                SUM(Payment) 'Payment' 
          FROM 
                PaymentDetails 
          GROUP BY AdmissionNum
    ) AS PD
    ON P.AdmissionNum = PD.AdmissionNum
WHERE 
    P.Fees - PD.Payment > 0
```

Comment: remaining fees is already getting calculated and saved in table.But with this query will i be able to get the only records whose remaining fees greater than 0?

Comment: `RemainingFees` in your details table is of not much use as extracting it would require you to first identify the latest record by ID and join that with the Details table again to get the corresponding remaining fees. Regarding records with remainingFees > 0, I just updated the query for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
   SELECT a.AdmissionNum, a.StudName , a.Fees, b.remFees as RemainingFees
   FROM Payment a, 
        (SELECT AdmissionNum, min(RemainingFees) as remFees 
           FROM PaymentDetails b GROUP BY AdmissionNum) b
   WHERE a.AdmissionNum = b.AdmissionNum 
        and b.remFees >0;
```

Comment: it's not to get min(RemainingFees) but max(date)

Comment: @Habibillah: I do see you answer. Its a different approach. You are assuming `final remaining fee` is the balance as of last date. I am simply getting the minimum balance as remaining fee is suppose to move downward only.

Comment: the question tell that "Remaining Fees is greater than 0 but the last details in the paymentDetais table". The last detail T think equal to Max(date)

Comment: @Habibillah: Please refer my updated comment. I agree but behaviorwise, remaining fee as of max date is same as minimum fee taking this as a simple case. I do understand, in complex business scenario, you can add more charges and remain fee can go up, but in that case current table structures will also not serve the purpose. I am not trying to make the question unnecessary complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try query bellow:

```
Select a.AdmissionNum, a.StudName, a.Fees, b.RemainingFees 
from Payment a 
inner join paymentDetails b on a.AdmissionNum = b.AdmissionNum
inner join (
   select AdmissionNum, max(date) as date 
   from paymentDetails 
   group by AdmissionNum
) c on a.AdmissionNum = c.AdmissionNum
where b.RemainingFees > 0 and b.Date = c.Date
```